# Best practice for persistent mobile connections on Android?

Tags: android, xmpp, websocket, real-time

I'm considering using a persistent connection to a "cloud service" from an Android app. This would  run all the time in a background service (or something like that).

I'm thinking of using web sockets or XMPP to keep the connection, basically looking for a light weight connection that won't drain battery. I **want to be able to push notifications in real time** to this connection, so periodic polling is not desired. *I am aware of C2DM and other commercial solutions, but am looking to roll my own*. This is why a web socket (or other light weight connection) is what I'm investigating. So if I go this route, what are some best practices I should be aware of?

I'm thinking of stuff like:

1. how to prevent the battery from draining,
2. How to handle IP address changes, etc?

Comment: Worth to reading Android docs: http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html

Comment: You need to split this into separate Android and iOS questions - the two are completely different (on iOS you can't simply have a background service).

Comment: @MartinH Question updated to be about Android only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but I think you may want to rethink your architecture.

Things you can expect out of a mobile platform

- Your IP address to change randomly
- Your physical internet connection to be lost randomly
- The OS to decide your not doing anything useful and killing your process
- The connection type changing randomly (from WIFI to 4G to 3G to edge) and thus your IP to change

Basically your app needs to be able to handle a loss of connection, because its almost guaranteed to happen.

That being said, it is totally doable depending on your definition of real-time.  If your willing to continually check that there is still a viable connection, you could keep any delays down to the minutes range.  But this will drain the battery and there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: Rethinking architecture is not a bad answer :-) This is the whole point of posting the question, just trying to vet the idea with others. If it's just a bad idea that's great feedback. Thanks. However I'm still interested in the best practices if one was do to it anyway. C2DM does it, so the question is: how do they do it and what are their best practices? The above comments are helpful things to look out for.

Answer (score 1):

Some things just don't go well together. That is *"push notifications in real time"* and *"prevent battery draining"*. You sure have to make compromises here.

I can only recommend to try some Android Apps that use XMPP to get a feeling how they handle persistent connections, IP address changes and battery consumption. If they are open-source you can also view the code and learn from it. Yaxim, Project MAXS and Beem to name a few. Maybe you shoud also have a look at [XEP-0286: XMPP on Mobile Devices](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0286.html)

That said, are you sure that you want to reinvent the wheel when Google offers you C2DM? Which is optimized for this use case. I think that it has some delay, so it's no where "real-time". But again, either you will end up with an solution that tries aggressivly to establish a persisent connection and drains the battery, or you will have to live with some kind of delay (~ 0-30 min).

Comment: Great link about XMPP on Mobile Devices. Some good design patterns outlined in that doc. Things like compression, and if you have to send then send everything you have since the power level will be stepped up at that point anyway, etc.

Comment: The ONLY reason I'm looking at alternatives to Google's C2DM is because C2DM requires the user to have a Google account on the device. I'm designing a push feature that will be productized and sold to Banks. Having to explain to them that their users will need google accounts will be a somewhat awkward conversation.

Comment: I know this is an old question but the rules for this have changed a bit for the GCM switch. Newer devices no longer need a Google Account. "It uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0 devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices running Android 4.0.4 or higher." - http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html